# "Unsupported characters in input" in Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, python-idle

I want to assign address of a file to a variable named 's':

```
>>> s= 'D:/4-Tutorials/Network/CCNA-farsi-shariaty/روش های آدرس دهی IP و Subnetting.mp4'
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s= u'D:/4-Tutorials/Network/CCNA-farsi-shariaty/روش های آدرس دهی IP و Subnetting.mp4'
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s='D:/4-Tutorials/Network/CCNA-farsi-shariaty/روش های آدرس دهی IP و Subnetting.mp4'.decode('utf8')
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s='D:/4-Tutorials/Network/CCNA-farsi-shariaty/روش های آدرس دهی IP و Subnetting.mp4'.encode('utf8')
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s='D:/4-Tutorials/Network/CCNA-farsi-shariaty/روش های آدرس دهی IP و Subnetting.mp4'.decode('utf-8')
Unsupported characters in input
```

As you see I returns me **Unsupported characters in input** error. and this error is because of the Arabic/Persian letters in the file name.

The weird thing is that I can write Arabic/Persian in IDLE and I can have a string variable containing Arabic/Persian letters:

```
>>> s = "سلام"
>>> s = "روش هاي آدرس دهي"
```

Finally I found that the origin of problem is one letter that has two different form between Persian and Arabic. It is "ی"  and "ي". Both indicate the same letter, first is for Persian and the second is for Arabic. (Arabic form has two dot (.) in under the letter).

As you see, I can't use one form:

```
>>> s = "ي"
>>> s = "ی"
Unsupported characters in input

>>>
```

How can I handle this issue? Is there anyway to add a font to IDLE for example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu + IDLE with no problem.

```
>>> a = "جادی"
>>> print (a)
جادی
>>> a
'\xd8\xac\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaf\xdb\x8c'
```

Check the Options ~ Configure IDLE ~ General menu. There you can set the UTF-8 and from the first tab you can choose your font.

Comment: Setting the default source encoding to utf-8 only helps when the source *is* utf-8 encoded. On Windows, this does not help when pasting even the line with the u prefix into IDLE's shell.  As with many unicode problems, Python 3 works better here.